# Translating a column containing comma separated codes

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

There is some data I'm trying to report on, one of the columns required contains a list of comma separated 2-character codes that I then need to "translate" back to the description it represents e.g. let's say it's about people and their personality traits. The data is stored like this:

| person_id | traits |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | OU,AD |
| 2 | AB,CD,EF,GH,IJ |

And say these "codes" represent descriptions like:

`OU = Outgoing`
`AD = Adventurous`

etc. So for person_id = 1 I'd want the output for Traits to be:

`Outgoing, Adventurous`

There is a set list of codes that could be listed, there is no lookup table to match the codes to their descriptions, and each record can have a different number of codes within the `traits` column.

What would be the best way to "translate" this column as above?

Comment: Fix your data model!  Storing comma-delimited values in a string is a SQL anti-pattern.

Comment: Split the string (there's literally 1,000's of duplicates of how to do this in [so]) and then `JOIN` to your lookup table (also plenty of dupes and there's documentation and tutorials too). Though the *real* solution is fix your design and stop storing delimited data in your RDBMS.

Comment: "Fix the data/design" is preaching to the choir - I have no control over this - and doesn't help solve my question as stated above, unfortunately.

Comment: If on SQL 2016 or higher there is the STRING_SPLIT function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 - if not then google Jeff Moden String Split or follow this link: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function

Answer (score 1):

You could just nest some [REPLACE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) functions... Not the most fancy solution, but it should work.

**Sample data**

```
create table people
(
   person_id int,
   traits nvarchar(100)
);

insert into people (person_id, traits) values
(1, 'OU,AD'),
(2, 'AB,CD,EF,GH,IJ');
```

**Solution**

```
select p.person_id,
       replace(                  --EF
       replace(                  --AD
       replace(p.traits,         --OU
       'OU', 'Outgoing'),
       'AD', 'Adventurous'),
       'EF', 'Efficient')
       as traits
from people p;
```

**Result**

```
person_id traits
--------- --------------------------
1         Outgoing,Adventurous
2         AB,CD,Efficient,GH,IJ
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e3d7e655beaa3b35216d9c9e30c17e0c) to see it in action.